# Ajax worked when scroll to the top not bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I struggling with this from yesterday. AJAX keeps showing when I reach the top of the page not the bottom of the page.

When I reach the bottom of the page, AJAX shows nothing: [When Scroll Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0acdM.png)

However when I reach the top of the page, the AJAX worked: [When Scroll Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN0Uj.png)

I want the AJAX to show when I reach the bottom of the page.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
  if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
    loadmore();
  }
});

function loadmore() {
  var val = document.getElementById('row_no').value;
  var val1 = document.getElementById('user_id').value;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getData.php',
    data: {
      getresult: val,
      getresult1: val1
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var content = document.getElementById('all_rows');
      content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + response;

      // We increase the value by 10 because we limit the results by 10
      document.getElementById('row_no').value = Number(val) + 10;
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are a little incorrect: what you want is to compare the `scrollPosition` to the difference between the viewport height and document height (the latter is `scrollHeight` in your code):

```
var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
if (scrollPosition === scrollHeight - viewportHeight) {
  loadmore();
}
```

The reason being that you know you are at the bottom of the page, when the position of the viewport from the top of the document is the difference between document height and viewport height. Here's a diagram that helps you understand:

[image]

To see it in a different light, you know you have scrolled to the bottom when **the sum of scrollTop and viewport height equals to document height**. When the user is not yet at the bottom, the sum will always be less than document height, i.e.:

```
if (scrollPosition + viewportHeight >= scrollHeight) {
    loadmore();
}
```

See proof-of-concept:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    if (scrollPosition + viewportHeight >= scrollHeight) {
      loadmore();
    }
  });

  function loadmore() {
    console.log('load more logic');
    
    // Insert load more logic here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Keep scrolling to reach bottom</strong></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in risus nisi. Morbi eu neque vitae massa accumsan tristique. Nulla quis ultrices leo, at commodo nunc. Aliquam mattis suscipit vehicula. Quisque finibus semper eleifend. Sed viverra interdum odio, et pretium tortor pharetra quis. Pellentesque lacus magna, porttitor a mauris eu, venenatis aliquet urna. Mauris velit tortor, sollicitudin eu pretium sit amet, ullamcorper commodo nisi.</p>

<p>Nunc non sodales nulla, et facilisis sem. Nunc interdum et tellus et finibus. Ut vulputate aliquet felis, quis consequat tellus vulputate et. Pellentesque tempus in mi in vestibulum. Morbi ut nulla magna. Vestibulum orci diam, malesuada vel nisi id, egestas finibus elit. Phasellus id vulputate leo. Morbi metus velit, aliquam eget ligula sed, lacinia fermentum enim. Maecenas malesuada nisi vel massa pellentesque, at mattis nibh iaculis. Vestibulum facilisis felis velit, ut finibus sapien venenatis eu. Vivamus gravida venenatis consequat.</p>

<p>Donec tempus ullamcorper est et mattis. Duis et sollicitudin nisi. Phasellus molestie, sem a dictum lobortis, justo sem consequat est, ut fringilla risus mauris pharetra ligula. Mauris nec nisl efficitur, elementum enim eget, tincidunt nibh. Morbi hendrerit dignissim enim commodo finibus. Nunc vitae quam quis eros molestie imperdiet. Maecenas commodo sit amet diam id feugiat. Praesent quis arcu porta, gravida dolor vel, porttitor justo. Fusce vitae arcu mattis, facilisis risus a, lacinia augue. Donec at mi a lectus accumsan iaculis.</p>

<p>Integer a turpis fermentum, ultricies magna et, interdum diam. Etiam ornare malesuada fermentum. Morbi suscipit non quam quis tempus. Vestibulum quis efficitur magna, in facilisis tellus. Etiam sapien purus, dictum in varius in, blandit id sapien. Donec interdum tempor nisi, in semper mauris. Etiam consequat blandit dapibus. Fusce volutpat ipsum vel erat ullamcorper sodales. Integer vitae pretium lectus. Mauris cursus, arcu eu condimentum aliquam, mi dui blandit urna, ut commodo massa leo a sem.</p>

<p>Donec auctor vestibulum turpis, at feugiat neque molestie ac. Vivamus tristique tempus sem, et rutrum ipsum sollicitudin hendrerit. Praesent a pretium leo. Maecenas elementum felis quam, eu gravida ante efficitur non. Sed a interdum neque. Cras eget auctor metus. Duis tempor, nisi ut sodales varius, sapien est aliquet nunc, non porttitor ipsum libero consequat odio. Vestibulum suscipit, quam et accumsan interdum, est leo semper nibh, ac gravida ante metus vitae justo.</p>
```